# Can sinch call emergency numbers like 911?

Tags: android, ios, sinch

Can sinch app-to-phoneline service be used to call 911 emergency services (using their iOS and Android SDKs)?

Code snippet on the iOS MainViewController.  I managed to invoke the callPhoneNumber method to call a regular PSTN line using sinch.  However, I cannot test a call to 911 because I do not wish to tie up a real emergency line.

How can I verify this code would work if the target phone number is 911?

thanks,

```
@implementation MainViewController

- (id<SINClient>)client {
    return [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] client];
}

- (IBAction)call:(id)sender {
    if ([self.destination.text length] > 0 && [self.client isStarted]) {
    id<SINCall> call = [self.client.callClient callPhoneNumber:self.destination.text];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"callView" sender:call];
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you have attempted to write for solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sinch does not support calling emergency numbers. As a general guideline, when calling with Sinch, phone numbers should be specified according to the E.164 number formatting (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) recommendation and should be prefixed with a ‘+’.